# How do I squeeze matplotlib bar x-axis labels to drop missing numerical values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My plotting function produces subplots, in which sometimes it receives regular data to plot by numerical order, and sometimes (case == 'special') the x-labels bars should have different, uniquely ordered numerical values. The problem is that I cannot seem to get rid of the x-axis spaces between the bars. any idea how to solve? thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

case = 'special' 

data = np.random.rand(10)

if case='regular':
    xvec0 = np.linspace(1, len(data), len(data), dtype='uint8')
else:
    xvec0 = np.array([3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 20])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 8))
fig.suptitle('Features Importance Summary', fontsize=16)

med_vec = np.ones(len(xvec0)) * np.median(data)
avg_vec = np.ones(len(xvec0)) * np.mean(data)
axs[0].bar(xvec0, data, edgecolor='k')
axs[0].plot(xvec0, med_vec, 'r--', label='Median')
axs[0].plot(xvec0, avg_vec, 'k--', label='Average')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Feature IDX', size=18)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Normalized feature importance', size=18)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))
axs[0].set_xticks(xvec0)
axs[0].grid(which='major', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.3', color='k')
axs[0].grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.1', color='k')
axs[0].legend()

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Plot always against `range(len(xvec0))`, later label xticks with `xvec0`.

Comment: Perfect! thank you! here's the working edited lines of code in case anyone else will encounter the same challenge:


    axs[0].bar(range(len(xvec0)), fi_wl, edgecolor='k')
    axs[0].plot(range(len(xvec0)), med_vec, 'r--', label='Median')
    axs[0].plot(range(len(xvec0)), avg_vec, 'k--', label='Average')

    axs[0].set_xticks(range(len(xvec0)))
    axs[0].set_xticklabels(xvec0)

Comment: You can post this as [your own answer and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Code cannot be formatted in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Mr.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t) here's a working code in case any one else in the future will encounter the same issue:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 8))
fig.suptitle('Features Importance Summary', fontsize=16)

med_vec = np.ones(len(xvec0)) * np.median(fi_wl)
avg_vec = np.ones(len(xvec0)) * np.mean(fi_wl)

axs[0].bar(range(len(xvec0)), fi_wl, edgecolor='k')
axs[0].plot(range(len(xvec0)), med_vec, 'r--', label='Median')
axs[0].plot(range(len(xvec0)), avg_vec, 'k--', label='Average')

axs[0].set_xlabel('Feature IDX', size=18)
axs[0].set_ylabel('Normalized feature importance', size=18)
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))

axs[0].set_xticks(range(len(xvec0)))
axs[0].set_xticklabels(xvec0)

axs[0].grid(which='major', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.3', color='k')
axs[0].grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.1', color='k')
axs[0].legend()
```

[image]